# What's the fastest way of opening the web inspector in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

So far I'm using right click inspect element to get to the console, but I want a quicker way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to launch the console is via the shortcut command - <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

There's a quicker way than the 3-key combo.

1 key: <kbd>F12</kbd> will also open the panel.

Comment: Agreed, on windows and linux this is the quickest method.

Comment: You can create similar on Mac with [Keyboard Remapping](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/).